# "Invalid parameter" when creating template message via Whatsapp API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, whatsapp-cloud-api

I'm getting this error, which says that the "example" parameter is missing when trying to create a template that contains variables in the body, but the parameter is present.

Error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Invalid parameter",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 100,
        "error_subcode": 2388043,
        "is_transient": false,
        "error_user_title": "O parâmetro \"components\" do modelo de mensagem não contém alguns campos esperados",
        "error_user_msg": "o componente do tipo BODY não contém o(s) campo(s) esperado(s) (example)",
        "fbtrace_id": "Aamlm3N3OYJcom4_2i2jZRn"
    }
}
```

POST URL:
`https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/132794263254451/message_templates`

JSON:

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "language": "pt_BR",
    "category": "MARKETING",
    "components": [
        {
            "type": "BODY",
            "text": "Olá, {{1}}! Lorem Ipsum...",
            "example": {
                "body_text": [
                    [
                        "Roberto"
                    ]
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I've tested other versions of the API and the error is always the same.

If I remove the body variable and the "example" parameter, the template is registered normally.

What am I doing wrong?